# How to use XSL variable in xsl:apply-templates?

Tags: xslt

I have a reasonably complex call to xsl:apply-templates:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="columnval[@id 
                                       and not(@id='_Name_') 
                                       and not(@id='Group') 
                                       and not(@id='_Count_')]"/>
```

The expression is reused in other places like this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="someothernode[@id 
                                           and not(@id='_Name_') 
                                           and not(@id='Group') 
                                           and not(@id='_Count_')]"/>
```

I want to generalize it somehow, so I can define it once and reuse it elsewhere. However, this doesn't seem to work:

```
<xsl:variable name="x">@id and not(@id='_Name_') and not(@id='Group') and not(@id='_Count_')</xsl:variable>
<xsl:apply-templates select="columnval[$x]"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="someothernode[$x]"/>
```

Is there a better / different way of doing this? All I want is to reuse the xpath expression in multiple different calls to xsl:apply-templates (some of which select from different children).

This is going to be used in a client application, so I can't use any extensions or switch to XSLT 2 unfortunately. :(

Thanks.

Comment: Good question. See my answer for a description of two possible solutions (XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0) and a hint of a more powerful, solution using higher-order functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't construct XPath dynamically in XSLT (at least, not XSLT 1.0).  But you can easily accomplish what you're trying to do using template modes:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="columnval" mode="filter"/>
<xsl:apply-template select="someothernode" mode="filter"/>

...

<!-- this guarantees that elements that don't match the filter don't get output -->
<xsl:template match="*" mode="filter"/>

<xsl:template match="*[@id and not(@id='_Name_') and not(@id='Group') and not(@id='_Count_')]" mode="filter">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="filtered"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="columnval" mode="filtered">
   <!-- this will only be applied to the columnval elements that pass the filter -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="someothernode" mode="filtered">
   <!-- this will only be applied to the someothernode elements that pass the filter -->
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: +1 this is an efficient approach. Only downside is that the filter is hardcoded and therefore not variable. If a variable filter is not needed, I would go with this solution.

Comment: Template modes made no sense to me at all until I started running into problems like OP's.

Answer (score 2):

Refactoring @Robert Rossney and @Tomalak

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="columnval" mode="filter"/> 
<xsl:apply-templates select="someothernode" mode="filter"/> 

<xsl:template match="*" mode="filter">
   <xsl:param name="pFilter" select="'_Name_|Group|_Count_'"/> 
   <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*
                                [not(contains( 
                                        concat('|',$pFilter,'|'),  
                                        concat('|',@id,'|')))
                                 and @id]"/> 
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Since attributes are by definition members of elements, you can replace the generic `node()` by `*`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at using an extension to xslt. I don't think you can do it in "standard" xslt.

This extension can do what you want: http://www.exslt.org/dyn/functions/evaluate/index.html

Comment: Updated question - we can't use extensions, since we're relying on MSXML to do the transform :(

Answer (score 1):

With the extension exsl:nodeset, you can create a named template that accepts a nodeset $x and returns the filtered nodeset according to your static predicate.

You can also define a function, in XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Updated question - unfortunately we are stuck with XSLT 1.0. :(

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
<xsl:variable name="filter" select="_Name_|Group|_Count_" />

<xsl:apply-templates select="columnval" mode="filtered" />
<xsl:apply-templates select="someothernode" mode="filtered" />

<xsl:template match="someothernode|columnval" mode="filtered">
  <xsl:if test="not(contains(
    concat('|', $filter,'|'), 
    concat('|', @id,'|'), 
  ))">
    <!-- whatever -->
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

You could make `$filter` a param, and pass it in from the outside for example.

What you cannot do (as you've noticed) is use variables to store XPath expressions.

Comment: Stupid question - why can you do that with parameters, but not variables?

Comment: @Colen: The variable (or param, for that matter) `$filter` stores a string, not an expression. I chose `|` as the delimiter. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Both XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0 do not support dynamic evaluation.

**One way to do this is using [`<xsl:function>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#stylesheet-functions) in XSLT 2.0 or [`<xsl:call-template>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#named-templates) in XSLT 1.0**.

```
 <xsl:function name="my:test" as="xs:boolean">
  <xsl:param name="pNode" as="element()"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vid" select="$pNode/@id"/>

  <xsl:sequence select=
  "$vid and not($vid=('_Name_','Group','_Count_')"/>
 </xsl:function>
```

**then you could use this function**:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="columnval[my:test(.)]"/>
```

**Certainly, you could specify the test in specific match patterns as suggested by Robert Rossney**, and this might be the best way.

In case you need to *dynamically* define which filtering function to use, one powerful tool is the **[FXSL](http://fxsl.sf.net)** library, which implements Higher-Order-Functions (HOF) in XSLT. HOF are functions that accept other functions as parameters and can return a function as their result.

Using this approach, you dynamically determine and pass to the `my:test()` as parameter a function that does the test.